# glm logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying out logistic regression on a dataset I have

```
model <- glm(feature1 ~ feature2, data=df, family="binomial")
```

But `glm` does something unexpected. It is taking all values of "feature2" as variables and assigns them coeff in the logit parameters in the model.

Output of summary(model) :

```
> summary(model)

Call:

glm(formula = feature1 ~ price, family = binomial(logit), data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.22931  -0.00008   0.00008   0.82033   1.97277  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   6.931e-01  1.225e+00   0.566    0.571
price0.06     1.887e+01  1.075e+04   0.002    0.999
price0.1     -6.931e-01  1.871e+00  -0.371    0.711
price0.11     1.887e+01  1.075e+04   0.002    0.999
price0.2      1.887e+01  1.075e+04   0.002    0.999
price0.9      1.887e+01  1.075e+04   0.002    0.999
price0.99     1.092e-01  1.269e+00   0.086    0.931
price1        1.253e+00  1.626e+00   0.771    0.441
price1.01     1.887e+01  1.075e+04   0.002    0.999
price1.02     1.887e+01  1.075e+04   0.002    0.999
price1.04     1.887e+01  1.075e+04   0.002    0.999

> typeof(nonNPpriceDf$price)
[1] "integer"
```

I want price to be just a predictor variable. I am not able to understand why all the prices are appended and treated as a variable.

Comment: Can you privde please `dput(df)` and `summary(model)`?

Comment: I'm guessing variable (it's a variable, not a feature :P) `feature2` is a factor?

Comment: That is normal for categorical variables (factors in R). What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: if i do typeof, it returns "integer" for feature2. It has numerical values in the dataset.

Comment: attached output of summary(model)

Comment: please show `class(df$price0)` and `table(df$price0)`

Comment: Factors are integers, with character labels for the levels the integer values represent.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a common misunderstanding of vector classes in R.

Comment: I didnt know the difference between typeof() and class() which is why I misinterpreted the factor variable as a integer variable. That answers my question. I converted feature2 to numeric and it worked fine. Thanks for the help you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a confusion between typeof and class methods. The typeof factor2 was Integer but the class was factor. I converted factor2 to numeric and it worked fine as expected.